# Localhost won't stop loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

I'm trying to connect to localhost:8081/status with the following code, but when I try to open the page, it loads forever. Changing the 8081 port to 3000 didn't solve this issue.

main.js

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import morgan from 'morgan'

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combine'))
app.use(bodyParser.json)
app.use(cors())

app.get('/status', (req, res) => {
    console.log('object');
    res.send({
        message: 'hello world'
    })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`app.use(bodyParser.json())` should fix your problem